# Mentioning the number of the Sefira prior to saying it

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer

Tha Halacha (Orach Chaim 489) http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14165&st=&pgnum=189 is that if for example on the Twenty eighth day of Sefira, you say "today is the Twenty eighth day" and you did not count yet - then you should count without a Bracha on that day. What is the Halacha if you would say "today is Chof Ches days in the Omer" can you still say a Bracha? Would there be a difference if you did the same on Lag B'Omer?

Comment: Are you sure your premise is true? I don't think you fulfill the mitzva if you don't mention the weeks, if you have intention not to fulfill it, or if you don't say "of the Omer," all of which are lacking from your opening example.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, _MB_ 489:7 says weeks are not necessary according to all and :8 says "of the _omer_" is not. I assume therefore (but CYLOR) that saying it would preclude counting with a _b'racha_.

Comment: @msh210: I stand corrected re: "of the Omer." However, MB 489:22 says that "the Acharonim" wrote that someone who doesn't mention weeks after the first six days *does* make a bracha afterward and that, so that's at least worth asking one's Rabbi and possibly not a problem. He also says, as I did, that explicit intention not to fulfill the mitzva is sufficient to make one still eligible to make the bracha later.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, re weeks, quite right, I stand corrected. Re intent to fulfill, right again, if he has explicit intent to not meet the obligation, not _s'tam daas_.

Comment: ...which, I see now, is what you said in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

*Beur Halacha* 489 s.v. "*Mone v'holech*" cites a difference of opinion whether counting with 'initials' (as in the question) counts. I'd *guess* that means that one who counted that way should not re-count that same night with a *b'racha*. But of course [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

**Update:** As discussed in comments on the question, one who omits the weeks' count also possibly meets his obligation (*MB* :7), yet counts again with a *b'racha* per the *MB* :22. Perhaps this case is similar? Again, CYLOR.

Comment: I suspect that the authorities quoted in MB:7 who say that one can fulfill even without mentioning weeks are not the same as those quoted in MB:22.